# Different struct types slices as argument to function in go

Tags: mongodb, go

I've being trying to generalise the following code to avoid redundant code duplication.

```golang
    func (db *MongoController) extractManyByIDFromDB(dbName string, collectionName string, pResults interface{}, limit int64) (int, error) {
         collection := db.client.Database(dbName).Collection(collectionName)
    
        findOptions := options.Find()
        findOptions.SetLimit(limit)

        // Passing bson.D{{}} as the filter matches all documents in the collection
        cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{{}}, findOptions)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
        }

        // Finding multiple documents returns a cursor
        // Iterating through the cursor allows us to decode documents one at a time
        i := 0 
        for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {

            // create a value into which the single document can be decoded
            var err error
            err = cur.Decode(pResults) //pResults is some *[]MyStruct
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            i++
        }

        if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        cur.Close(context.TODO())

        return i, err

    }
```

I'm trying to populate an array data given by the argument  `pResults`, right now the code doesn't succeed in decoding with `cur.Decode()` to `MyStruct`.

The goal is to being able to pass not only `MyStruct` but also to analyse `MyOtherStruct` and my `MyAmazingStruct`, without having to develop separate `extractManySpecificStructByIDFromDB` for each new struct I want to extract from the DB.

I tried to search a result for it online, none of my searching worked eventually.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Cursor.All](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor.All)

```
func (db *MongoController) extractManyByIDFromDB(dbName string, collectionName string, pResults interface{}, limit int64) error {
    collection := db.client.Database(dbName).Collection(collectionName)

    findOptions := options.Find()
    findOptions.SetLimit(limit)

    // Passing bson.D{{}} as the filter matches all documents in the collection
    cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{{}}, findOptions)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
    err := cur.All(context.TODO(), pResults)
    cur.Close(context.TODO())
    return err
}
```

Use the slice length to determine the number of elements decoded.

```
var results []Example
err := c.extractManyByIDFromDB(db, coll, &results, limit)
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
fmt.Println("%d documents extracted", len(results))
```